# JRE equivalent for Python

Tags: python, environment-variables, development-environment, environment

Does Python have a development environment? I am not referring to IDEs, but to the actual execution environment like JRE is for Java. How does Python code execute on various heterogeneous platforms? Who performs the linking, assembly and execution of Python code?

Comment: Please restrict each post to a single question. Asking several questions in one post is frowned upon and can lead to closure from the question becoming too broad or it being unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Python interpreter is its runtime [this][1] and [this][2] article explore all the details you want to know.


  [1]: http://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/04/02/pythons-innards-introduction/
  [2]: http://akaptur.github.io/blog/2013/11/15/introduction-to-the-python-interpreter/

Comment: @AbhishekBansal this is what I was looking for. Post it as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @amey91 I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python interpreter is its runtime.

[this](http://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/04/02/pythons-innards-introduction/) and [this](http://akaptur.github.io/blog/2013/11/15/introduction-to-the-python-interpreter/) article explore all the details you want to know.

Comment: Now you have a "link only answer", which [are not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: Well, that is actually what I was looking for :)
And I don't see any other answers here, so this is the best one.